# Remove certain rows and columns in multiple csv files under the same folder in R

Tags: r

I have a ton of files with the exact format, and I would like to remove the first six rows and certain columns (columns 2 through 8, 12 through 16, 18 through 23, etc) for all of them. Preferably I also don't want the processed files to overwrite the original ones. I'm pretty sure there's a way to do that in R but just haven't figured it out yet. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

These tidyverse code might help.

```
library(tidyverse)

files <- list.files(".", pattern = ".csv")

dat <- files %>% 
  map_dfr(
    ~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
      slice(7:nrow(.))
  ) %>% 
  select(-c(2:8, 12:16, 18:23))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a function to import data sets as .csv file and within the function, u can specify the removal of columns and then removal of rows, etc and at u can return that data

```
library(tidyverse)
data_imp_fun<- function (path="C:/Users/xyz/Documents/data1.csv") # you can change path when u tried to import a data
{
file_path=(paste(Path))
data<-read_excel(file_path)
data<-data[,!names(data) %in% c("column2 name","column8 names",column16 name")]# this line will help you removing you desire columns just input the names of each column you #want to remove
data<-data[-c(1:6),] # this line will help you to remove first six rows
return(data)
}
```

now you can import data as

```
data_1<-data_imp_fun(path="C:/Users/xyz/Documents/data1.csv")
data_2<-data_imp_fun(path="C:/Users/xyz/Documents/data2.csv")
```

I hope this will help you alot

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to loop through all the files tho? It seems like I need to manually import every csv file?

Comment: in that case, you have to define arguments for function path and file name you can use the paste function to build up the name of path and then make a list of names of all files and then by using for loop or apply function u can import every CSV file easily, but again loops and apply functions