# Deleting excess rows from csv files in R and then combining csv files

Tags: r, csv

I have over 200+ csv files containing temperature data from iButton data loggers. The csv files that are created in onewireviewer have 14 rows of data that I need to get rid of in all of the csv files (see the image below) so that I can then merge csv files based on the column headings.

[Onewireviewer output csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szAkA.png)

Id love to be able to automate it in some way as I have around 70 folders (basically one folder per location) with 2-3 csv files from onewireviewer in each folder.

Ive tried messing around with bits of code Ive found online but I couldnt get anything to work and Im now just incredibly frustrated. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

If it helps I did try running the tidy verse code found here [Remove certain rows and columns in multiple csv files under the same folder in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67762624/remove-certain-rows-and-columns-in-multiple-csv-files-under-the-same-folder-in-r) but I get this error:

Column specification -----------------------------------------------------

Delimiter: ","
chr (1): 1-Wire/iButton Part Number: DS1921G-F5

i Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.

i Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.

x Locations 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. don't exist.

i There are only 1 column.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

In addition: Warning messages:

1: One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details

2: One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details

Comment: Welcome; I'd suggest you separate this into two problems.  Come up with a successful script for reading in one file. Then design the reading over the folders and files and merging.  People really would prefer that you not put images of data, but your image makes the data look simple once you skip the top rows. Only three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list.files(...), fread, skip = 14, ...), ...)
```

where `...` are function's arguments.
check out `?list.files`, `?data.table::fread` and `?data.table::rbindlist` to find out more about them.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed!